# Change way to detect end of block ply yacc

Tags: python, if-statement, yacc, ply

I'm doing a python to c++ translater. Right now I'm finishing my syntaxical grammar and I'm having a little problem with my if-else block.
The thing is that I can't figure out to detect end of block with the tabulations.
Right now I got this file to test :

```
print(33)
if a<3:
    print(test);
b=5
```

It gives me the following result:

```
Program
|  print
|  |  '33'
|  if
|  |  < (2)
|  |  |  'a'
|  |  |  '3'
|  |  Program
|  |  |  print
|  |  |  |  'test'
|  =
|  |  'b'
|  |  '5'
```

Which is correct, beause b=5 is at the same level as my if.
 Here are my lex tokens :

```
reserved_words = (
    'if',
    'print',
    'range',
    'for',
    'in',
    'while'
)

tokens = (
    'COMPARATOR',
    'IDENTIFIER',
    'ILLEGAL',
    'FLOAT',
    'INT',
    'EQU',
    'ENTER',
    'POINTS',
    'TAB',
    'END'
    ) + tuple(map(lambda s:s.upper(),reserved_words))



literals = ';():\s'

def t_ENTER(t):
    r'\n'
    return t



def t_ADD_OP(t):
    r'\+|-'
    return t

def t_POINTS(t):
    r':'
    return t

def t_EQU(t):
    r'\='
    return t    

def t_MUL_OP(t):
    r'\*|/'
    return t

def t_COMPARATOR(t):
    r'[<>]'
    return t


def t_INT(t):
    #r'\d+(?!\.)(?![a-zA-Z])'
    r'\b(?<!\.)\d+(?!\.)\b'
    try:
        t.value = t.value   
    except ValueError:
        print ("Line %d: Problem while parsing %s!" % (t.lineno,t.value))
        t.value = 0
    return t

def t_ILLEGAL(t):
    r'\d+[a-zA-z]+'
    try:
        t.value = t.value   
    except ValueError:
        print ("Line %d: Problem while parsing %s!" % (t.lineno,t.value))
        t.value = 0
    return t

def t_FLOAT(t):
    r'\d+\.{1}\d+'
    try:
        t.value = float(t.value)   
    except ValueError:
        print ("Line %d: Problem while parsing %s!" % (t.lineno,t.value))
        t.value = 0.0
    return t

def t_IDENTIFIER(t):
    r'[A-Za-z_]\w*'
    if t.value in reserved_words:
        t.type = t.value.upper()
    return t

def t_TAB(t):
    r'[ \t]{4}'
    return t

def t_newline(t):
    r'\n+'
    t.lexer.lineno += len(t.value)


def t_error(t):
    print ("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0])
    t.lexer.skip(1)

t_ignore = ' '

lex.lex()
```

And my rules :

```
    vars = {}

def p_programme_statement(p):
    ''' programme : statement  '''
    p[0] = AST.ProgramNode(p[1])

def p_programme_recursive(p):
    ''' programme : statement ENTER programme '''
    p[0] = AST.ProgramNode([p[1]]+p[3].children)

def p_statement(p):
    ''' statement : assignation
                        | structure '''
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_expression_num_or_var(p):
    '''expression : INT
        | FLOAT 
        | IDENTIFIER 
        '''
    p[0] = AST.TokenNode(p[1])

def p_statement_print(p):
    ''' statement : PRINT '(' expression ')' '''
    p[0] = AST.PrintNode(p[3])

def p_expression_comp(p):
    ''' expression : expression COMPARATOR expression'''
    p[0] = AST.OpNode(p[2],[p[1],p[3]])

def p_structure_if(p):
    '''structure : IF expression POINTS ENTER programme ';' '''
    p[0] = AST.IfNode([p[2],p[5]])

def p_structure_while(p):
    ''' structure : WHILE expression POINTS ENTER programme '''
    p[0] = AST.WhileNode([p[2],p[5]])

def p_expression_paren(p):
    '''expression : '(' expression ')' '''
    p[0] = p[2]

def p_assign_block(p):
    ''' assignation : TAB IDENTIFIER EQU expression'''
    p[0] = AST.AssignNode([AST.TokenNode(p[2]),p[4]])

def p_assign(p):
    ''' assignation : IDENTIFIER EQU expression '''
    p[0] = AST.AssignNode([AST.TokenNode(p[1]),p[3]])

def p_error(p):
    print ("Syntax error in line %d" % p.lineno)
    yacc.errok()
```

The thing is : *my p_Structure_if is wrong* because right now I say that end of block is when the ';' appears. How can I do to detect end of block by checking tabulations (if next line not at same tabulation level of the other, then it's not same block and then not using ';' characthers?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies in advance that this isn't a complete answer, but it's more than fits in a comment and I hope it's useful to you.

The official Python documentation includes a [BNF grammar for the full language](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html).

The tricky part is that you need to generate an appropriate amount of "dedent" tokens to go along with the tabs (what the official grammar calls `INDENT`). As well, we only really care about whitespace at the beginning of a line.

The `t_TAB` regex would need to be something like `^[ \t]*` (since you need to be able to do the check for lines that don't have any leading whitespace, so that you know when the code has returned to top level). However, that of course (by design) matches an empty string, so it needs to be tested only once per line - I'm not sure `ply` is up to the task, or at least I don't know offhand how to make that work.

Anyway, you would then need to inspect the whitespace string inside `t_TAB()` to figure out which indentation level it corresponds to (use a stack of previously seen indentation strings, if you want to match Python's formal behaviour; if you want something stricter then I guess you can just do math on the number of tabs/spaces), and emit either a single INDENT or else zero or more DEDENTs (that's the other thing I'm not sure of, whether ply supports generating multiple tokens from a single token regex - you might need to hack around with the `t.lexer` attributes or something).

Comment: thank you for your answer ! i'll try tomorrow and keep updated, but got an idea or two already, cheers !

Comment: you were right, t_TAB match empty string... how can I manage to do math on the number of spaces or tab ?